# a:link around div - styling inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I want to be clickable, so I've wrapped an "a" tag around it, as it is valid HTML 5 and made the div a block level element.

Now, the problem I'm having is styling content inside that div, as everything displays as a link, and despite trying numerous methods I haven't found a good solution for custom styling everything inside the div.

A reduced test sample can be viewed here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aencq

So, my question is basically, what's the best way of styling elements such as h2 and p that are inside a block level div, that is wrapped with an a:link.

Comment: [This is a bit confusing though (Firebug screenshot)](http://pangram.net/sandbox/text-decoration.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need here is:

```
a { color:black; text-decoration:none; }
```

Sometimes you'll want to get more specific and then you can be like:

```
a h2 { color:red; }
```

Comment: You'd probably want to class the `a` link though. [Like this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdzmD).

Comment: Either that or target the `a` through its parent such as `.parent a`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what is happening to you is that all elements under <a> tag are **inheriting** css properties of a hyperlink (underline, blue color, etc)

To counter this create an id or class on your  tag and remove/override the default anchor properties.

For example to remove the underline you do:
    text-decoration: none;

After that override Link-related pseudo-classes: **:link**, **:visited**, **:hover** and **:active**.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is a matter of opinion. To me the best way would be to use the most succinct CSS as possible. Use only the [specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) that you need. For example don't use `a div h2` when `a h2` is all that's needed. Also FYI you can do something like `a.block { display:block; }` and then you won't need the div in the markup.