# text-decoration: apparent discrepancy between appearance and computed values

Tags: css

I noticed this (oddity?) when playing around with code related to [a:link around div - styling inside div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595357/alink-around-div-styling-inside-div)

Given this HTML:

```html
<a id="foo" href="foobar">
  <div id="bar">
    <h2 id="baz">Foo</h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

And this CSS (background colors added to show structure):

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
}

#bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
}

#baz {
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xD6f9/)

---

Chrome shows the matched CSS rules as containing `text-decoration: none;` yet the text is indeed underlined:

[image: Chrome Console]
<sub>(source: [pangram.net](http://pangram.net/sandbox/td-chrome-console.png))</sub>

---

Similarly, using Firebug, Firefox returns `null` for the `textDecoration` computed style:

[image: Firebug]
<sub>(source: [pangram.net](http://pangram.net/sandbox/td-firebug.png))</sub>

[MDN says that `text-decoration` applies to all elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration).

I realize there's an easy workaround of just applying the `text-decoration` property to the `a` link, but this is not the behavior I would have expected. Can anyone explain this (apparent) discrepancy?

**Edit:** I believe the answer is here: [Line Decoration: Underline, Overline, and Strike-Through](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration)

> When specified on or propagated to a block container that establishes
>   an inline formatting context, the decorations are propagated to an
>   anonymous inline box that wraps all the in-flow inline-level children
>   of the block container.

But I still don't completely understand what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome and Firefox underline hyperlinks by default, as you're probably aware.

What's happening here is that while `text-decoration` gets *computed* to `none` on `#baz` (as specified in your CSS rule), the *used value* ends up being `underline` as a result of propagating the browser's default style from its ancestor, the `a` element. This used value *replaces* the computed value when rendering the page onto the canvas, but as far as the DOM is concerned, the computed value remains `none`, based on cascade resolution alone.

So, the discrepancy here lies in the difference between a computed value and a used value. The definitions can be found in [section 6.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#value-stages).

This behavior of propagating `text-decoration` values into descendant boxes, which takes place *independently of the cascade*, is outlined [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props):

> When specified on or propagated to an inline element, it affects all the boxes generated by that element, and is further propagated to any in-flow block-level boxes that split the inline (see [section 9.2.1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)).

Comment: Turns out this behavior is more complicated than I thought (usually the case with me ;-) Merely adding `position: fixed/absolute` or `float: left/right` also removes the underline as it removes the element from the inline flow. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xD6f9/11/)

Comment: @steveax: Yeah, most of that is covered in the prose for `text-decoration`, and even then some parts are left out in CSS2.1, e.g. block-level tables. (Are they in text-decor-3 yet?)

Comment: I'm gonna accept this one (and why am I not surprised BoltClock got the accept?) but I think it's not really the difference between the computed and used values, but rather due to [decorations are propagated to an anonymous inline box that wraps all the in-flow inline-level children of the block container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#line-decoration). Certainly close enough though!

Comment: @steveax: Ah, I'd interpreted your question as asking why there was a discrepancy in computed and rendered values while already being aware of the propagating behavior. Also, no need to flatter me ;)

Comment: BoltClock, just to clarify, from reading the specs I believe that the `text-decoration: underline` property isn't applied to the `h2`, but rather to the generated anonymous inline box. That how you read it?

Comment: @steveax: I'm not too familiar with how HTML5 interacts with CSS in terms of the `a` element (it shouldn't matter either way), but if it's an inline-level box then it is propagated into *both* the block box generated by `h2` (as an in-flow block box that splits the inline `a` box), *and* in turn the anonymous inline box within `h2`.

Comment: @steveax: Scratch that - since any text that flows inline within a block is supposed to be treated as an anonymous inline box, then yes it's that inline box that's receiving the decoration.

Answer (score -1):

you need to put the `text-decoration: none` on the `a` link to remove the underline

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xD6f9/2/)

i think the underline is still there because the element is inside the `a` link or `a` tag the browser recognized it as a link, but has no text-decoration on the element itself..

Comment: Yep, I said in my question that was a solution to not having an underline, but that's not my question.

Comment: -1 OP specifically stated in the question that he's aware of that. The question was **why**.

Answer (score -1):

"text-decoration" is the property of 'a' tag... so just add it to 'a' tag and its working...see the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xD6f9/3/)

```
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: -1 OP specifically stated in the question that he's aware of that. The question was **why**.

Comment: Again, not my question. To restate: why do the browsers report the element as not having text-decoration?

Comment: @steveax: Yes, 'text-decoration' applies for all the elements...But in the case mentioned by steveax, the 'text-decoration' style refers the default value of 'a' tag only.. See the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xD6f9/6/)... that property works for the h2 tag too.. So the solution is to style the 'a' tag only...

Comment: Interesting fiddle. It does show that the `text-decoration: underline` property is coming from somewhere other than the property on the `h2`